# Microprocessor pinout problem. How many pins do I need for given N buttons?

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

At the begginning I'd like to sorry for the long intro, but I think it helps in fully understanding the problem. Of course the math problem is much shorter, so **if you are not interested in the full story, just skip to Math problem header**.

---

### Story

I recently got my AtMega32. I started creating some example circuits and I think I found a cool math problem.

So, lets start with how does button input work. Button is a very simple part, it just physicaly connects its pins if its pressed. From the software side, I can check if a given pin of microprocessor is currently powered. So basicaly, if I want to test if the given button is pressed, I just connect vcc (power) to one button pin, and the other button pin to one of the processor pins.

[image: Img1]

Now when I want to test if btn1 is presed I just check if pin1 is powered. Simple enough?

Okay, lets move further. If I have let's say 3 buttons, I have to connect each one to another pin, just like I did with first one:

[image: Img2]

Now it seems that if I want to connect N buttons, I need N pins on microprocessor, right?

Actually not. Another cool feature of microprocessors is that they can set power to some of the pins which are defined as outputs. So, let's say I need 6 buttons. It seems that I need 6 free pins, but I'm able to connect it using only 5. How? This circuit demonstrates:

[image: Img3]

Okay, I have to grant it, I'm a bad drawer. But, I hope I can explain it somehow. Firstly, Red pins are outputs, Green pins are inputs. Darker and Lighter cables don't cross. At first, I power up pin6, and check all inputs 1-3. Then I switch the power to pin7 and again I check all inputs 1-3. Now, programmers would know how it works, this is pseudo-code:

```
output: boolean buttons[6];

o = 0;
while (o < outputNumber)
{
    setPowered(o);

    i = 0;
    while (i < inputNumber)
    {
        if (isPowered(i))
            buttons[outputNumber * o + i] = true;
        else
            buttons[outputNumber * o + i] = false;
    }

    setUnpowered(o);
}
```

Now in the array `buttons` I have states for each of 6 buttons, using only 5 pins (3 in, 2 out)! Of course, I could use 3 outputs and 2 inputs, same technique. For this math problem lets assume the processor has infinte speed, so the number of iterations is not important.

Let's also say that I can't connect any button to VCC directly, so to have 3 buttons I need 4 pins (3 in, 1 out, instead of 3 in all connected to vcc).

Now my problem is: **How many pins do I need to connect N buttons?**

I came up with:

---

### Math Problem

We have given sequence defined as:

$$a_n = minimal\;(a+b)\;where\;a*b\ge n$$

where $a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}; a,b,n \gt 0$

How to easily calculate N-th element of that sequence? For example, what is $a_{1000}$?

First elements are (assuming $a \ge b$):

- $a_1 = 2$, a = 1, b = 1
- $a_2 = 2$, a = 1, b = 1
- $a_3 = 3$, a = 2, b = 1
- $a_4 = 4$, a = 2, b = 2
- $a_5 = 5$, a = 3, b = 2
- $a_6 = 5$, a = 3, b = 2
- $a_7 = 6$, a = 3, b = 3
- $a_8 = 6$, a = 3, b = 3
- $a_9 = 6$, a = 3, b = 3
- $a_{10} = 7$, a = 4, b = 3

Comment: Better hope nobody pushes three buttons at the same time. (And are you sure you don't mean micro_controller_ rather than processor?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yep, I did. In my language it means exactly same, I will correct it in a minute :) Pushing three buttons wouldn't break the mechanism, would it?

Comment: It doesn't "break" it irreversibly, but in your last diagram if you push the first three buttons in your last diagram, there will be an indirect connection between pins 2 and 7, so it looks like the fourth button is also pressed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ahh, I see now. Inserting diodes would deafinitely do the job :) Anyway, great you pointed it out, I didn't notice it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $k$ pins and want as many buttons as we can get with that many pins. As a function of $a$ that is $ab=a(n-a)$ buttons, and the graph of this is parabola with maximum at $a=k/2$.

So if you have an *even* number of pins, the optimal number of buttons is reached by selecting $a$ and $b$ to be equal (half of the pins). If there's an *odd* number of pins, you get the same maximum result for $a=\frac{k-1}{2}, b=\frac{k+1}{2}$ or vice versa.

Therefore, if you desire $n$ buttons, then $2\lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil$ pins will certainly do, where $\lceil\sqrt n\rceil$ is the square root of $n$ rounded *up* to the nearest integer. $2\lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil-2$ will be too few, but $2\lceil\sqrt n\rceil-1$ *might* work.

It's not too difficult to derive a formula that tells you exactly when to subtract 1 and when not to, but it's simpler and less error-prone simply test whether it works.

Comment: What I thought about just before posting the question was that this problem is simmilar to "rectangle with surface area n with lowest possible perimiter". Actually, the only problem is when can I subtract one and keep it working...

Actually I think I know when I can possibly subtract 1. In my opinion. At the example of 18. sqrt(18) = ~4.24, so we take 5 and (5 or 4), 4 is enough here (we can subtract 1). Based on my tests, if sqrt(n) - floor(sqrt(n) < 0.5 we can subtract one. Prove me if Im wrong.

Comment: @kittyPL: It's thereabouts, at least. As a practical matter, if your formula gives the same results as your hand-computed ones for small $n$s, then I would trust that you've got all of the fenceposts accounted for correctly.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it! Thanks! :)